# Find modulus of a number in array representation and a divisor

Tags: c, math

I have an array of unsigned integers as follows

```
unsigned coeffs[] = { x_(n-1), ... , x_1, x_0 }
```

representing the number < x_(n-1) ... x_1 x_0 > with base 10.

Now I want to find out the modulus of this number given a divisor( unsigned integer) and came up with the following function written in C using Horner's rule.

```
unsigned modulo(unsigned coeffs*, unsigned degree, unsigned divisor)
{
    int r = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < degree; ++i)
        r = (r * 10 + coeffs[i]) % divisor;
    return r;
}
```

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong here? x)

Comment: To migitate overflow, you could do: `r = (((r * 10) % divisor) + (coeffs[i] % divisor)) % divisor;`

Comment: Looks fine provided that `divisor < UINT_MAX / 10 - 10`. If `divisor` is larger the calculation can overflow.

Comment: Note: for type consistency, use `int r = 0;` --> `unsigned r = 0;`

Comment: @Micrified [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062197/find-modulus-of-a-number-in-array-representation-and-a-divisor#comment87141194_50062197) does help, but only a little as `r * 10` can readily overflow when `r > UINT_MAX/10`.  Yet this idea is sound: to insure each `*` and `+` respect the `unsigned` range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find modulus of a number in array representation and a divisor
>   Is this correct or am I doing something wrong here?

#### With small `divisor`, no problems.

[@Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062197/find-modulus-of-a-number-in-array-representation-and-a-divisor#comment87141532_50062197) identified when a large `divisor` fails the code. (given that `unsigned r` was used instead of `int r`).  I derived a slightly different limitation

```
divisor <= (UINT_MAX - 9)/10 + 1
```

Should code need to deal with large `divisor`, then one has two approaches:

1) Use a wider type:

```
// Consider some wider type like unsigned long long or uintmax_t
_Static_assert(ULLONG_MAX > UINT_MAX, "Oops");
typedef unsigned long long unsigned2x;

// Might as well make `unsigned coeffs*` `const`  and `size_t` for indexing.
unsigned modulo(const unsigned coeffs*, size_t degree, unsigned divisor) {
  unsigned2x r = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < degree; ++i) {
    r = ((r * 10) + coeffs[i]) % divisor;
  }
  return (unsigned) r;
}
```

2) Perform the *mod* in parts:

An approach offered by: [@Micrified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062197/find-modulus-of-a-number-in-array-representation-and-a-divisor#comment87141194_50062197) fails when `r * 10` overflows.

To cope with the case when no wider unsigned integer exists and code must handle a large `divisor`, use the below which uses code from [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485)

```
// when `unsigned` potentially as wide as `uintmax_t`
unsigned modulo(const unsigned coeffs*, size_t degree, unsigned divisor) {
  unsigned r = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < degree; ++i) {
    r = mulmodmax(r, 10, divisor);
    r = addmodmax(r, coeffs[i], divisor);
  }
  return r;
}
```